# How to set a fixed field value as a url_for('blueprint.route')

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

```
class GuideForms(FlaskForm):
  FileField = FileField('FileField')
  FileFiled_hidden = HiddenField()
  text = HiddenField()

  text.data = url_for('admin.gen')
```

The code above result in this error:

> "Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being"
>   RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.

Is there a way to define the fixed value of a field (text), as a url_for?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, python generates its forms before its routes. So its basically impossible to define a form value as a url_for('blueprint.route').

The workaround you must do is:
Set a value for form.field.data when the form is used in a route.

```
@blueprint.route("/upload")
def upload():
  form = GuideForms()
  form.text.data = url_for('admin.gen')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when creating an instance of this form,
try,

```
class GuideForms(FlaskForm):
   FileField = FileField('FileField')
   FileFiled_hidden = HiddenField()
   text = HiddenField()

   def __init__(self, , *args, **kwargs):
       super(GuideForms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       text.data = url_for('admin.gen')
```

And make sure you create an instance of this form when there is application context